# How to use 'mailTo' for multiple email recipients?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is the following syntax correct?

> var mailto = new Uri(String.Format("mailto:{0}&subject={1}&body={2}",
>   "akiptev@gmail.com, fozzi@gmail.com" , subject, message));
>
> apiResult.Result = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354142/winrt-bulk-send-email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
<a href='mailto:recipient1@domain.com,recipient2@domain.com'>Email Link</a>
```